# regression with factors (from factor analysis)

Tags: regression, anova, multivariate-analysis, factor-analysis

I have n=100 and measures =500. Using dimensionality reduction, I want to contruct latent variables with 500 variables and test each factors in an anova model.What is the nest approach to create latent variables.

I was looking at R function factanal which is uses ML approach. My matrix is singular and it gave me an error. I tried removing the variables which are highly correlated , still it doesnt work .Is there any other way to find which variables in my matrices can be made from other variables?

When I tried R function principal from package psych , it gives me a warning

> The determinant of the smoothed correlation was zero.
>   This means the objective function is not defined.
>   Chi square is based upon observed residuals.
>   The determinant of the smoothed correlation was zero.
>   This means the objective function is not defined for the null model either.
>   The Chi square is thus based upon observed correlations.
>   Warning message:
>   In cor.smooth(r) : Matrix was not positive definite, smoothing was done"

Can I use the factors from this result for further regression or anova type of analysis .

How are these two methods(factanl/principal) different?

Comment: Try using one of the Partial Least Squares modules. This is an approach to factor analysis appropriate when *p* is greater than *n*.

Comment: You mean Partial least squares Path Analysis?

Comment: That's a hybrid of PLS...which is a method unto itself.